# How to use math mod function in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

How to use math mod function in flex?

calculate like this 7 mod(%) 2 = 1 any help

Comment: Why not to use [corresponding operator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#modulo) you mentioned?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AS3 has the `%` operator so you can just do `7 % 2`